# How to convert time into a corresponding slot in DataFrame Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, time, mapping

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'name':['a','b','c'],'time': ['18:15:10','06:16:03','11:51:01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I plan to convert the time int a slot. For example, map time within `('00:00:00'-'00:59:59')` as `1`, map 
time within `('8:00:00'-'8:59:59')` as `9`.

how can I add a column to `df` such that my final `df` is

```
name    time          slot
'a'     '18:15:10'      18
```

Also what if I what to convert time within `('00:00:00'-'5:59:59')` as `1`.  In this case, my time slot has large period.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've got your idea correctly.

First, convert your `time` column to `timedelta64`:

```
df['time']=pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])
```

If you only want convert time within **every `x` hour(s)**, the answer is pretty simple:

```
import numpy as np
x = 5
ranges = [(i,i+x) for i in range(0,24,x)]
df['slot'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x:[t<= (x/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')) <T for t,T in ranges].index(True)+1)
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
|    | name   | time            |   slot |
|----+--------+-----------------+--------|
|  0 | a      | 0 days 18:15:10 |      4 |
|  1 | b      | 0 days 06:16:03 |      2 |
|  2 | c      | 0 days 11:51:01 |      3 |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

And if you want custom flexible time ranges, which may be **as precise as `h:m:s`**, you should:

```
ranges = [('0:0:0','12:0:0'),('12:0:0','23:59:59')]
ranges = [pd.to_timedelta(i) for i in ranges]
df['slot'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x:[t<=x<T for t,T in ranges].index(True)+1)
```

Result:

```
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
|    | name   | time            |   slot |
|----+--------+-----------------+--------|
|  0 | a      | 0 days 18:15:10 |      2 |
|  1 | b      | 0 days 06:16:03 |      1 |
|  2 | c      | 0 days 11:51:01 |      1 |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the first method. It say `ValueError: True is not in list`, I use python 3. Any though?